# How to extract multi-nested values from JSONs in T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, nested-json

I am using SSMS v18.12.1, and am trying to write a T-SQL query to extract specific values from multiple columns, and at times nested values.

In the example below, I would like to extract the DeliverySchedule @Type value, and the Details @Type and Details:candyLimit @Type value

```
{
    "@type": "Test",
    "OrderId": 6608216,
    "deliverySchedule": {
        "@DeliveryType": "Test",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "Snickers",
                "id": 657117,
                "candyLimit": {
                    "@type": "UNRESTRICTED"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am still pretty new to extracting JSON data. I have tried utilizing suggestions from other StackOverflow questions, have tried using an OPENJSON similar to this,
but it is not returning the results I expected

```
select * from openjson((select [description] from #OrderHistory)
,'$.deliverySchedule.details[1].candyLimit[1].@type'
)
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
select * from #OrderHistory OH
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OH.description)
```

Returns Key/Value pairs in separate columns, and the Value column still has nested JSON

```
select * from openjson((select [description] from #OrderHistory)
,'$.deliverySchedule.details[1].candyLimit[1].@type'
)
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
select * from #OrderHistory OH
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OH.description)
```

Returns Key/Value pairs in separate columns, and the Value column still has nested JSON

Comment: Fyi the version of ssms is irrelevant, it's only a client ui, we need the version of the engine i.e. `select @@version`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to chain together some `OPENJSON` calls with explicit schema ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0eXmgvlp))

Arrays are zero based so you need `[0]` not `[1]` (if you are specifically interested in the first array element only as seems to be the case from the code you posted) and `candyLimit` is just an object so doesn't need any index at all.

```
SELECT      deliverySchedule."@type",
            details1."@type",
            candyLimitType
FROM        #OrderHistory OH
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OH.description) 
    WITH ( "@type" VARCHAR(20), 
            details1 NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.deliverySchedule.details[0]' AS JSON ) deliverySchedule
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(details1) 
    WITH ( "@type"       VARCHAR(10), 
           candyLimitType NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.candyLimit."@type"') details1
```

Comment: you can use ""-names in paths to escape special chars, like: $."some json field"

Comment: @siggemannen  - thanks. I thought I'd tried that!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in flat values (ie. the first array value), you can use JSON_VALUE directly:

```sql
create table #json (j nvarchar(max))

insert into #json
SELECT N'
{
    "@type": "Test",
    "OrderId": 6608216,
    "deliverySchedule": {
        "@DeliveryType": "Test",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "Snickers",
                "id": 657117,
                "candyLimit": {
                    "@type": "UNRESTRICTED"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}'

select json_value(j,'$."@type"'), json_value(j,'$.deliverySchedule."@DeliveryType"')
, json_value(j, '$.deliverySchedule.details[0]."@type"')
from #json
```